# While em carrossel dinâmico

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, while

Estou tentando exibir as imagens no carrousel Bootstrap com o while.

Consigo acessar o array com todas urls, mas não estou conseguindo inserir na tag img no while, tentei while com foreach para exibir as imagens mas não esta funcionando.

Já os indicadores estão exibindo corretamente mas com um indicador a mais, como faço pra não contar o `0`?

```
<?php
            $this_post_id = get_the_ID();
            $urls =get_post_meta($this_post_id,'my-images', true);
            $totalUrls = count($urls);//conta urls no array
            $number = 0; 
        ?>      

  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php while($number <= $totalUrls){ ?>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $number++; ?>"></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <?php 
  while($number <= $totalUrls){
     foreach($urls as $url){
        ?>
            <div class="item active"> // como deixar classe active apenas na imagem ativa
      <img src="<?php echo $url;?>"  class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
     <?php  $number++ 
       } //end foreach
   } //end while
?>
 </div>
```

**Atualizado**

```
<?php
            $this_post_id = get_the_ID();
            $urls =get_post_meta($this_post_id,'my-image-for-post', true);
            $totalUrls = count($urls);//count urls in array
            $number = 0; 

        ?>      


  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php while($number < $totalUrls){ ?>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $number++; ?>"></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <?php foreach($urls as $url){ ?>

    <div class="item active">
      <img src="<?php echo $url;?>"  class="img-responsive" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Com ajuda do usuario  Anderson Carlos Woss,

Corrigi a condicional para: enquanto $number ser `<` que $totalUrls, isso corrigiu o problema nos indicadores.

Deixei o while apenas nos indicadores, o foreach para exibir as imagens e consigo ver todas imagens lá se tiverem todas com a classe `active` na  `<div class="item active">`

Como faço para deixar apenas 1 imagem com a classe active dentro do foreach?

Agradeço ajuda

Comment: Com o `while` e `foreach`, você estaria percorrendo a lista duas vezes, isso se o valor de `$number` estivesse correto, que não me parece. No primeiro `while`, você incrementa o valor de `$number`, então no segundo `while`, `$number` já chega com um valor superior à `$totalUrls`, não entrando no laço. Comece tentando tirar o segundo `while`.

Comment: Muito obrigada @AndersonCarlosWoss consegui resolver as repetições, atualizei minha pergunta, só falta deixa uma unica imagem com a classe "active"

Comment: Obrigada @AndersonCarlosWoss resolvido, coloquei uma resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Apenas formalizando a resposta.</sub>

Dado o código:

```
<?php
    $this_post_id = get_the_ID();
    $urls =get_post_meta($this_post_id,'my-images', true);
    $totalUrls = count($urls);
    $number = 0; 
?>      

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <?php while($number <= $totalUrls){ ?>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $number++; ?>"></li>
      <?php } ?>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <?php 
          while($number <= $totalUrls){
              foreach($urls as $url){
      ?>
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="<?php echo $url;?>"  class="img-responsive" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
      <?php 
                  $number++ 
              }
          }
       ?>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Primeiro, começamos com a lista de indicadores. Quando for mesclar códigos PHP de controle com códigos HTML para marcação, uma maneira prática de se fazer, em alternativa ao utilizar os `{}` no `while` é utilizar as diretivas `while: .. endwhile`, desta forma:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <?php while($number <= $totalUrls): ?>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $number++; ?>"></li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</ol>
```

Pois assim, caso seu código HTML seja muito extenso, fica claro qual é o bloco de código que está sendo fechado em `endwhile`. Apenas com `}` poderia ser qualquer bloco de contexto: `for`, `while`, `function`, `class`, etc.

Agora, na listas de imagens. Como disse no comentário, nesta parte você possui dois laços de iteração, `while` e `foreach`. O primeiro erro de lógica está aí, pois os dois iteram sobre a variável `$urls` e, desta forma, você estaria percorrendo a lista duas vezes, o que não parece ser proposital. O segundo erro de lógica está em utilizar a variável `$number` como controle no `while`, sem *resetar* seu valor. No laço para definir os indicadores, você incrementa o valor de `$number` de 0 até `$totalUrls`, permanecendo neste último valor, logo, na instrução `while($number <= $totalUrls)`, o `while` seria executado apenas uma vez (o que explica o porque utilizou o `foreach`). Para melhorar o código nesse aspecto, basta utilizar apenas o `foreach`:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <?php foreach($urls as $url): ?>
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="<?php echo $url;?>"  class="img-responsive" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Visto, agora, que deseja que apenas o primeiro item da lista esteja ativo, sua solução é funcional, porém redundante. Você repete muito código apenas para escrever `active` a mais. Uma forma de contornar isso é:

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <?php foreach($urls as $i => $url): ?>
    <div class="item <?php echo ($i == 0)? "active" : ""; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $url;?>"  class="img-responsive" />
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Perceba o código PHP onde estaria a classe `active`. Fiz o uso do operador ternário para definir se deve ser impresso aclasse `active` ou não. A lógica é a seguinte: se `$i` for zero, imprima `active`, se não, imprima nada. O valor de `$i` vem do laço `foreach($urls as $i => $url)`, sendo o índice de cada *url* no vetor.

Comment: Muito obrigada Anderson, super didática sua resposta eu até tinha esquecido da existência do operador ternário, muito obrigada novamente

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver assim:

```
<?php
            $this_post_id = get_the_ID();
            $urls =get_post_meta($this_post_id,'my-image-for-post', true);
            $totalUrls = count($urls);//count urls in array
            $number = 0; 
            $initUrls = 0;

        ?>      


  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php while($number < $totalUrls){ ?>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $number++; ?>"></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <?php 

            while($initUrls < $totalUrls){
                foreach($urls as $url){
                if ($initUrls++ === 0) {
    ?>
                <div class="item active">
              <img src="<?php echo $url;?>"  class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                ...
              </div>
            </div>  
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="<?php echo $url;?>"  class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                ...
              </div>
            </div>
        <?php   
            }

            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: marque a resposta